# I have written a Python function that extracts text from PDFs. I need help dealing with this type of error

Tags: python, subprocess

```
def extract_clean_text_lisible(path_input, path_output):

    if spawn.find_executable("pdftotext"):
        path_input = current_app.config['PROJECT_PATH']+path_input
        path_output = current_app.config['PROJECT_PATH']+path_output
        pdftotext = current_app.config['POPPLER_PATH']+"/pdftotext.exe"
        out, err = sp.Popen([pdftotext, "-layout", "-enc", "UTF-8", path_input, "-"], stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE, stdin=sp.PIPE)
        fichier = open(path_output, "w", encoding="utf-8")
        s = out.decode("utf-8")
        fichier.write(s)
        fichier.close()
    
    else:
        raise EnvironmentError(
            "pdftotext not installed. can be downloaded from https://poppler.freedesktop.org/"
        )
    return out.decode("utf-8")

out, err = sp.Popen([pdftotext, "-layout", "-enc", "UTF-8", path_input, "-"], stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE, stdin=sp.PIPE)
```

```
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable Popen objec
```

Comment: `Popen` doesn't return a sequence you can unpack to two names `out` and `err`, were you thinking of e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate?

Comment: the thing is... This function is written by someone who works with me, I still don't understand why he used out and err

Comment: Why are you asking us instead of them?

Comment: because when I asked him he didn't help me... he was like I don't know why you get an error when using this function

Comment: We can't tell you why they _don't_ , as the error and the docs tell you a `Popen` object isn't iterable.

Comment: Okay ! So if  I assign the popen object to out and remove the err variable because Popen object isn't iterable. do you have any idea how to print or save the output text because popen doesn't have a decode attribute

Comment: Please read the linked docs, which provide all kinds of examples on how to actually use `Popen`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Have found a solution to this function:

def extract_clean_text_lisible(path_input, path_output):

```
if spawn.find_executable("pdftotext"):
    path_input = current_app.config['PROJECT_PATH']+path_input
    path_output = current_app.config['PROJECT_PATH']+path_output
    pdftotext = current_app.config['POPPLER_PATH']+"/pdftotext.exe"
    out = sp.Popen([pdftotext, "-layout", "-enc", "UTF-8", path_input, "-"], stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE, stdin=sp.PIPE)
    text = out.communicate()[0].decode('utf-8')    
    fichier = open(path_output, 'w', encoding='utf-8')
    fichier.write(text)
    fichier.close()

else:
    raise EnvironmentError(
        "pdftotext not installed. can be downloaded from https://poppler.freedesktop.org/"
    )
return out.decode("utf-8")
```

you can use this function to extract clean text from pdfs and store it in a specified path.

be sure to install poppler and Tesseract to use this function.

Answer (score 0):

For such a basic command in windows you don't need python just simply send a shortcut of the pdftotext.exe to any location, but desktop is easiest.

[image]

Then change the properties as required, so in this case add `-layout -UTF-8, you can add any icon, then for any one pdf you can drag and drop on the icon

[image]

**And instantly you get the text file in the same folder**

[image]

For multiple files or a folder of PDFs you would need a more complex shortcut (still possible as one line), such that its easier to write a line or two in a cmd file to pass the variables.

Comment: Thanks for your help! But it is not the case... because this function is implemented in a flask app to automate invoice processing

Comment: I tried it... It works!